# Multiple errors & Bubble sort error

Tags: c#, sorting, search, binary-search, bubble-sort

I don't fully understand the bubble sort so while doing some practice I ran into a few errors I cannot figure out.

My Code:

```
static void SortCharacters(Character[] characters)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Which field would you like to sort by? (Name, WeaponName, TotalDefense)");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userInput.ToLower() == "name")
    {
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < characters.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (characters[j] > characters[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = characters[j + 1];
                    characters[j + 1] = characters[j];
                    characters[j] = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
                }

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(characters[i] + " ");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    else if (userInput.ToLower() == "weapon name")
    {

    }
    else if (userInput.ToLower() == "totaldefense")
    {

    }
}
```

Errors:

1. Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character' and 'Character'.
2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'BinarySearch.Character' to 'int'.
3. Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'BinarySearch.Character'.

Comment: What is the definition of `Character` here?  Is this a class you created?

Comment: Assuming `Character` is a class with properties, I think you want to sort based on the values in the selected property, not on the whole object itself.  Posting your `Character` class code and perhaps some sample data will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string` instead of `Character[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code, I think here are your problems:

> 1. Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character' and 'Character'.

This line causes the error: `if (characters[j] > characters[j + 1])`. Because the type of `characters[index]` is `Character`, you cannot just compare like that. I think what you want is comparing its `name`. So, the statement should be:

```
if (characters[j].Name > characters[j + 1].Name)
```

> 2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'BinarySearch.Character' to 'int'.
> 3. Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'BinarySearch.Character'.

The causes is this:

```
int temp = 0;

// Some code here

temp = characters[j + 1];
characters[j + 1] = characters[j];
characters[j] = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
```

You can see the type mismatched error here. You are trying to assign `Character` to `int` and vice versa. To fix this, you should change the type of `temp` to `Character`:

```
//int temp = 0; Don't do this

Character temp; // Do this

// Some code here

temp = characters[j + 1];
characters[j + 1] = characters[j];
characters[j] = temp;
```